# Select the row which have variables in the text field

Tags: php, mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have a MySQL table with a text field, lets say the field name is Car. Car's type is text. 
I have also some variables like name, product number, date, description, address, price, etc.

Now I want to select from that table, only the row which have my variables found in Car field value.

For example, I want to find only the row which match with my variables, and if Car text is the following and if my variables are `name = Honda`, `product number = 4222`, `date = 20131223`, `description = very cool`, `address = Street 59`, `price = 15000`.

```
<category>Compact car
<name>Honda XxX
<colour>Black
<productnumber>4222
<date>20131223
<code>US
<description>very cool
<address>Street 59
<price>15000
// ...
```

Then MySQL query will output only this row. And I would like also as second variant, to output the similar rows which have only one variable which do not match, for example if  price do not match then is fine.

I am not sure how to do this with MySQL; maybe somebody knows and can help.

I think something like this will work for first variant.

```
Select * From Car Where Car LIKE "%name%" AND Car LIKE "%productnumber%" AND ....
```

Maybe somebody knows a better, faster way. For example, is the following better?

```
SELECT LOCATE("name", Car) AND LOCATE("productnumber", Car)
```

I must not split car column into several colums, this is a condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **definitely** want to split your `car` column into several columns (one for each piece of information). Then the query will become straightforward, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM _table WHERE name = 'Honda' AND product_number = 4222 ...
```

... but given your constaint, you could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM _table
WHERE
    car LIKE '<name>Honda XxX' AND
    car LIKE '<productnumber>4222' ...
```

If you use prepared statements, you might want to use this template query instead:

```sql
...
WHERE
    car LIKE CONCAT ('<name>', ?) AND
    car LIKE CONCAT('<productnumber>', ?)...
```

But allow me to insist: if your application is meant to go in production, and if you are planning to serve more than a handful of users, or if there are more than a handful of records in this table, tell whoever is in charge that this structure is very, *very* poor. No index can be used, and it will become unusable very soon.

Comment: I must not split car column into several colums, this is a condition

Comment: @ManY Please see my alternative suggestions.